# CMAKE include src and install directories on different OS

Tags: c++, cmake

I am learning to use CMake and trying to understand where should I place files from different open-source libraries when I download them. I am talking about install location.

On linux include directory is this by convention: /usr/local/include/

What is default location for Windows and Mac OS?
I know that these locations can change, but what is the most common location I should place them?

Can something like this work?

```
install(FILES include/sort/sort.hpp DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}/sort)
```

Comment: What for are you downloading them? How is "putting open-source libraries when you download them" relevant to CMake?

Comment: I am more talking about installation process.
I am simply downloading just Eigen and Boost.

Comment: Please, ask a **single question** per question post. Windows and MacOS, each has its own specific about "usual" installation directory. Include directory is normally somewhere under the installation one. As for "source folders", I don't think that any OS has some default place for sources.

Comment: There is no default location for Windows which would be widely accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows usually the install prefix is something like `C:/Program Files/<Package Name>`, the usual install prefix on Unix being `/usr/local`. Usually this directory contains subdirectories like `include` containing the headers, `lib` containing (import) libraries, ect..

Using MSVC for the Windows targets those include directories are not automatically available to the compiler.

This is the reason why you should try to use `find_package`, if package configuration scripts or find scripts are provided by the installation which has the added benefit of also adding any dependencies with just 2 commands in your cmake project (`find_package` and `target_link_libraries`). If the package is installed in the default location, `find_package` should be able to locate the scripts to load without specifying the install location manually.

For packages not providing this kind of info, writing a find script of your own creating imported targets allows for easy reuse.

---

> Can something like this work?
>
> ```
> install(FILES include/sort/sort.hpp DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}/sort)
> ```

In general you should avoid hardcoding absolute destination paths into your install paths. Instead use destination paths relative to the install prefix, since the install prefix may be overwritten, e.g. if the user runs the installation via `cmake --install <build dir> --prefix <install directory>` or when using `cpack` to generate a package.

Usually you place public headers of your library in a separate directory, even in your sources (which you seem to be doing) and install the directory with

```
install(DIRECTORY include/sort TYPE INCLUDE)
```

Resulting in cmake choosing the exact location based on its defaults for the include files for the target system.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer.
I have a follow up question:
Do you know why on windows cmake adds a project name in CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: C:/Program Files/<Package Name> but on linux just /usr/local, is it a normal behavior?

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL Probably a historic decision. My guess would be that the open source nature of linux had a major influence on these conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross-platform package manager instead of manually managing the included directories. It handles the differences between different platforms.

[vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) is one of the best package managers currently available. You can easily use it via [project_options](https://github.com/aminya/project_options/).

Comment: Sadly I had to many problems with vcpkg installing often too many files taking a very long time. I really prefere to avoid any package manager.

Comment: vcpkg builds the packages from the source. If you set up caching, the second time you build it will reuse the cache. The cache can be even reused on GitHub Actions
https://github.com/aminya/setup-cpp#inside-github-actions